# Printing from Phone to Hp Printer via Wifi

Tags: android, pdf, printing

I have saved My ListView items as a Pdf file in local Storage,but not able to print the Pdf file and also can't open it.
It shows the error like this  :  "Cannot display pdf (myfile.pdf is in Invalid format)"

```
File fileDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "Android/data/mypackage/");   

        if (!fileDir.exists())
            fileDir.mkdirs();


        File newFile = new File(fileDir, fileName+ ".pdf");

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile, false));

    /*
     * Write a header row.
     */
        bw.write("Description" + "\t\t\t" + "Value");

    /*
     * and a row for each result, comma separated
     */
        for (int i = 0; i < jewelleryDetailsList.size(); i++) {
            String row = new String();
            row = jewelleryDetailsList.get(i).getLine1()
                    + "\t\t" + jewelleryDetailsList.get(i).getLine2();
            bw.write(row);
        }

        bw.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create like this, you are trying to use "way to create txt file" for making pdf, but it's not possible to do like that.

For creating pdf you have many options such as:

1. iText Library ([ItextTutorial)](https://www.codeproject.com%20%E2%80%BA%20Mobile%20Development%20%E2%80%BA%20Android)
2. droidText Library ([DroidText](https://github.com/bullda/DroidText))

There are many, you can use any of them. It's very easy to learn.